# Django not show image on the view

Tags: python, html, django, image

Here my view look :

[image]

when i inspect element, it given image source are :

```
127.0.0.1:8000/store/arm-list/apple.jpg
```

and :

[image]

so here my code :

urls.py :

```
urlpatterns = [

 path('arm-list/', VechileListView.as_view(), name='arm-list'),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

views.py :

```
class VechileListView(ListView):
model = Vechile
template_name = 'store/arm_list.html'
context_object_name = 'arm'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    # Call the base implementation first to get a context
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    # Add in a QuerySet of all the books
    context['vendor'] = Vendor.objects.all()
    return context
```

settings.py

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'store/images')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

models.py

```
enter code here
class Vechile(models.Model):
 no_polisi = models.CharField(max_length=10)
 alias = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
 photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='', null=True)
 ....
```

arm_list.html

```
enter code here
 {% if arm %}
             {% for arm in arm %}
              <tr>
                   <td class="serial">{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
                   <td><img src="{{ arm.photo.url }}"></td>
                   <td>{{ arm.alias }}</td>
                    .....
                    ...
              {% endfor %}
```

here my file structure

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you are facing is that you have set the `MEDIA_URL` to `/media/`. so if you change the `MEDIA_ROOT` to `/media` and upload all files to `media/store/images` then it should work.

like this:

**settings.py**

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**models.py**

```
class Vechile(models.Model):
    ....
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='store/images')
    ....
```

I hope this solves you problem.

Comment: can you share you `models.py` ?